# What is the difference between Max Cardinality and Min Cardinality?

Tags: database, data-modeling, cardinality

I am having a hard time understanding what is the difference between the Max and Min cardinalities when trying to design a  database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remember cardinality is always a relationship to another thing.

**Max Cardinality(Cardinality)**
Always 1 or Many.  Class A has a relationship to Package B with cardinality of one, that means at most there can be one occurance of this class in the package.  The opposite could be a Package has a Max Cardnality of N, which would mean there can be N number of classes

**Min Cardinality(Optionality)**
Simply means "required." Its always 0 or 1.  0 would mean 0 or more, 1 ore more

There are tons of good articles out there that explain this, including some that explain how to even property ["diagram"](http://www.tdan.com/view-articles/7474).  Another thing you can search for is Cardinality/Optionality (OMG Terms) which explains the same thing, Optionality is "Min" Cardinality is "Max",

---

From http://www.databasecentral.info/FAQ.htm

> Q: I can see how maximum cardinality is used when creating relationships between data tables. However, I don't see how minimal cardinality applies to database design. What am I missing?
>
> A: You are correct in noticing that maximum cardinality is a more important characteristic of a relationship than minimum cardinality is. All minimum cardinality tells you is the minimum allowed number of rows a table must have in order for the relationship to be meaningful. For example, a basketball TEAM must have at least five PLAYERS, or it is not a basketball team. Thus the minimum cardinality on the PLAYER side is five and the minimum cardinality on the TEAM side is one.
>
> One can argue that a person cannot be a player unless she is on a team, and thus the minimum cardinality of TEAM is mandatory. Similarly an organization cannot be a basketball team unless it has at least five players. The minimum cardinality of PLAYERS is mandatory also. One could argue in the opposite direction too. When a player quits a team, does it cease to be a team until a replacement is recruited? It cannot engage in any games, but does it cease to be a team? This is an example of the fact that each individual situation must be evaluated on its own terms. What is truth in THIS particular instance? The next time a similar situation arises, the decision might be different, due to different circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with other answers, here's a slightly different view.  Think in terms of *optionality* and *multiplicity*.  Take an example: `Person` has `Address`.

Optionality asks: Does every `Person` need to have an `Address`?  If so the relationship is unconditional - which means minimum cardinality is 1.  If not, then min cardinality is 0.

Multiplicity asks: Can any given `Person` have more than one `Address`?  If not, the maximum cardinality is 1. If so the maximum cardinality is >1.  In most cases it's unbounded, usually denoted `N` or `*`.

Both are important.  Non-optional associations make for simpler code since there's no need to test for existence before de-referencing: e.g.

```
a=person.address()
```

instead of

```
if (person.address !=null) {
  a=person.address()
}
```

Addresses are a good example of why Multiplicity is important.  Too many business applications assume each person has exactly one address - and so can't cope when people have e.g. holiday homes.

It is possible to further constrain the cardinality, e.g. a car engine has between 2 and 12 cyclinders.  However those constraints are often not very stable (Bugatti now offers a 16 cylinder engine).  So the important questions are optionality and multiplicity.

hth.

Comment: Neat and simple, such examples easily beat theories, long articles in getting a fundamental grasp.

Answer (score 0):

Let's work with an example -

`Students` takes `Class`. Here both `Students` and `Class` are entities.A School may or may not have students enrolled in a particular semester. Think of a school offering courses in summer semester but no student is interested to join in. So, student's cardinality can be **(0,N)**. But if a `Class` is going on means, it should have at least 1 student registered. So, its cardinality should be **(1,N)**. So, you should check whether the entity participating in the relation is **partial** or **total**, which decides it's cardinality in the relation.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Maximum Cardinality:**
1 to 1, 1 to many, many to many, many to 1

**Minimum Cardinality:**
Optional to Mandatory, Optional to Optional, Mandatory to Optional, Mandatory to Mandatory

Answer (score 0):

To your question, 'what is the use of optionality in database design?':
 It becomes very helpful in the scenarios like the following.

When you design 2 tables with 1-to-1 relation, you will be confused to decide where (in which table) to have the foreign key. It's very easy to decide it, if you have optionality 1 for one table and 0 for the other table. The foreign key should be present in the former. There are many other uses for it as well.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum Cardinality:- one-one, one-many, many-many

Minimum Cardinality:- zero or one

[This link](http://tdan.com/crows-feet-are-best/7474) describes my answer, why it is so, what's the representation,
and what it is.